# I think I install the tomcat correctly , but why it can't run correctly?

Tags: tomcat

I can visit my localhost, but there are many Error in my program.

[image]

Comment: Error is quite self explainatory. What we can't see is how you installed Tomcat, how are you running it (standalone or from IntelliJ), how did you deploy your app...

Answer (score 0):

There is some configuration you did that is pointing to an non-exist directory path.

open your terminal and execute `cd <error's dir path>`

Comment: When I run tomcat instruction sh shartup.sh ,  then:
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
Is there anything errors?

Comment: the error is /Users/sightmaple/Libary/Caches/IntelliJIdea2017.1/tomcat/index_jsp_the_first/conf does not exist. Probably a bad configuration of your IntelliJ server integration